# How to use numberKeyListener to get keyPressEvents from the Android Dialler

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, onkeypress

Can someone help me to get keypress events from the android dialler. can someone help me with it and should i use number key listener for it? I need my service to fire when the user presses 999 on the dialler.

Im just wondering wether i shud use a service for this or a broadcast reciever because i need the same input while the phone is locked or unlocked

Thank you
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL to detect the out going number (in your case it is 999) and then you can start your service . follow this link
http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=A2DD7A11C804B7C7646DCA883AA452FC?recipeId=1151

Comment: Thanx sujit i have done that but its going to be a hectic for the user to keep on dialling numbers to start the service so can i use something like a keypressevent for that?

Comment: there is no direct way to detect Key press event of dialer , is default application of android , u only can able to get the status of that button using your application services

Answer (score 0):

> I need my service to fire when the user presses 999 on the dialler.

Fortunately, this is impossible from an SDK application. Otherwise, any application could spy on what phone numbers a user dials.

Comment: is there a way for me to fire a service when the phone is locked? using a special code or smthing...mine is like an emergency app so incase of an emergency u dont wanna be unlocking ur phone or if somebody else is using he wouldnt know the code as well soo how can i sort this out?

Comment: @Roses: "is there a way for me to fire a service when the phone is locked?" -- you can listen for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcasts. That is the closest thing I am aware of.

Comment: but then whats the use of the methods like dialerKeyListener?

Comment: @Roses: DialerKeyListener is a class, not a method. It is used to write a dialer.

Comment: can i use it to replace my dialler?

Comment: @Roses: Only if you are making your own firmware with your own dialer.

Comment: can i run a service that listens to my keypressevents?

Comment: I wrote a broadcast reciever that fires the same service if you are dialling the emergency number and it worked. so im thinking there should be a possibility of doing it..